# Como puedo agregarla opcion de descargar imagen en webview android studio

Tags: android-studio, webview, webview-android

Buen dia amigos, estoy creando una serie de webviews con android studio pero no logro hacer posible que el usuario pueda descargar las imagenes de la web (webview).

La accion que necesito es muy común, cuando el usuario deje el dedo presionado aparezca la opción de "descargar imagen"

Dejare part de mi MainActivity para que me ayuden.

**MainActivity**

```html
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv);
        CustomWebViewClient c = new CustomWebViewClient();
        wv.setWebViewClient(c);
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html"); //Change path if it is not correct
        } else {
            wv.loadUrl("//MY-URL//");
        }

        wv.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    }


    // Function to load all URLs in same webview
    private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            if(url.contains("//MY-URL//")) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadResource(WebView  view, String  url){
            if (!DetectConnection.checkInternetConnection(MainActivity.this)) {
                wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html"); //Change path if it is not correct
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Creo que este enlace te puede venir bien para eso:
**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379174/download-images-using-android-webview** Espero que te sirva :D

Comment: hola ya habia visto ese enlace y la verdad es que no me funcionó o no supe colocarlo, sobre todo el setDownloadListener lo marca como error D: @hello

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema que tienes al tratar de realizar la descarga?

Comment: hola como estas no he podido agregar el cogido que me indico el otro usuario, tal vez lo estoy colocando mal, lo estoy colocando antes de la llave que cierra el "protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)" no se  si puedo agregar una captura de pantalla (la dejo acá: http://prntscr.com/n84ypj ).

Agregué los permisos de WRITE y READ External_Storage.

Genero la apk pero el webview sigue sin permitirme hacer esa acción, espero puedas ayudarme.

Si necesitan que coloque algunas otras partes del código por favor avisame @Elenasys

Comment: Es importante agregues el mensaje de error desplegado en el LogCat, realizaste la petición de permisos manualmente?

Comment: @Elenasys te comprendo, ya no me da error, de hecho pude armar la apk sin problema par testearla en varios moviles, el caso es que la acción no se ejecuta en el webview y es lo que me tiene un poco loco